# Get definition of unknown object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, definition

Is there any way to get the definition (public methods and properties) of an object in Javascript that is unknown?

In reality, I know what the object should be, but it's having problems accessing Methods that should be there, so I want to see what Methods are defined.

I have no control over this object so I can't use JSON or toString.
Any other ideas?

Comment: what do you mean unknown ? can you create an instance of it ?

Comment: Why can't you use JSON?  If you can see the object, you can use JSON.

Comment: I tried using JSON and it didn't work.  Potentially I did something wrong.

Comment: Don´t you get a nice object tree in firebug if you `console.log(myObject);`?

Comment: No, I get a reference error because the object is an ActiveX control and doesn't work in Firefox. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out "Javascript: The Good Parts", page 23 on reflection.

Some notes:  use for(key in o) to enumerate the members of o.  This will include members inherited via the prototype chain.

You can use o.hasOwnProperty(name) to determine if something is a direct member of an object, or included via the protoype chain.

You can use typeof() to distinguish functions from properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you already expecting a known type of object, but still rather would like to check either particular method exists, you could do this with:

```
if ("method" in object) ....
```

Comment: for debugging you could also use Firebug extension on Firefox, there you can simply dump an object and see what methods/properties it has...

Comment: Debugging is what I'm trying to do.  However this object is an ActiveX object that only works in IE...so is there an equivalent action in IE's Web Developer Tools?

Comment: there is also Firebug Lite, 100% JavaScript solution, but for this you need to be able to include somehow JS file. See their page for more details:

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Answer (score 0):

If you have VS 2005 have a look at [Debugging client JavaScript in VS 2005](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5918/debugging-client-javascript-in-vs-2005/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `function_name.prototype.constructor`